# Using Cauchy Sequences in Uniform Continuity

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences, uniform-continuity

I'm self studying analysis right now, and I ran into a problem. Most of the proofs I've seen for this problem are done through delta-epsilon. I was wondering if my solution was correct or not.

**Problem:** Sps. $f$ maps from $(0,1)$ to the complex plane and is uniformly continuous. Prove $f$ is bounded.

**What I did** Suppose $f$ is unbounded. This means that there exists a sequence $x_n$ converging to $x$ in $(0,1)$ such that $f(x_n)$ diverges to either infinity or negative infinity. However, since $x_n$ is convergent, it is thus Cauchy since the reals are complete. This, as $f$ is uniformly continuous $f(x_n)$ is Cauchy as well. Since Cauchy sequences are always bounded, this means that $f(x_n)$ is bounded, and thus cannot diverge. Thus, $f$ is bounded.

Comment: (0,1)? Try $f(x)=1/x$, $f$ is considered as a map to complex plane, but $f$ is not bounded.

Comment: Woops just noticed a huge typo. Updated

Comment: Haha oooook. That's more like it. Thanks for editing the typo, because initially it was like "No; false; lies and falsehood." haha

Comment: How do you know that the sequence $x_n$ converges? What is $x$?

Comment: For the sequence to be unbounded, there must be a sequence $x_n$ converging to some $x$ in $(0,1)$ so that $f(x_n)$ diverges as $n$ goes to infinity. I'm just defining a sequence that I'll later prove is unattainable.

Comment: How do you know $x \in (0,1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main idea is fine, although it's unclear what you mean by $x$, and it certainly does not have to be the case that $x\in (0,1)$, but the proof can still work. A slight alteration is:

If $f$ were unbounded, then there exists a sequence $x_n \in (0,1)$ such that $f(x_n) \rightarrow \infty$ or $-\infty.$ Since the sequence $x_n$ is bounded it has a convergent subsequence $x_{n_k}$, and also for this subsequence $f(x_{n_k}) \rightarrow \infty$ or $-\infty$. But since $x_{n_k}$ converges, it is Cauchy, and thus $f(x_{n_k})$ is Cauchy, since the image of a Cauchy sequence under a uniformly continuous function is Cauchy. However Cauchy sequences are bounded, which contradicts the assumption that $f$ was unbounded.